# Insert sort on a linked list

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, insertion-sort

I want to do insert sort in a linked list without using dummy nodes.

This is my code. How can this be improved? Any input is appreciated.

```
public static Node insertSort(Node node){

   Node sortedList = null;
   while(node != null){
    Node current = node;
    node = node.next;
    Node x;
    Node previous = null;
    for(x = sortedList; x != null; x = x.next){
        if(current.value < x.value){
                break;
         }
         previous = x;
    }
    if(previous == null){               
          current.next = sortedList;
          sortedList = current;
    }
    else{               
       current.next = previous.next;
       previous.next = current;
    }
  }
  return sortedList;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Algorithmically, your implementation seems fine. One improvement would be to initialize the sortedList to the first node right away. This necessitates some error checking up front, which I think is better style anyway.

I would also run a check for the current node being the new sorted head first. That way I can automatically assume that I'm inserting after the search position. That allows elimination of the `previous` variable.

But this is all stylistic stuff to make the logic flow easier to understand. As I said, I think your implementation functions perfectly well.

```
public static Node insertNode(Node node) {
    if (node == null)
        return null;

    // Make the first node the start of the sorted list.
    Node sortedList = node;
    node = node.next;
    sortedList.next = null;

    while(node != null) {
        // Advance the nodes.
        final Node current = node;
        node = node.next;

        // Find where current belongs.
        if (current.value < sortedList.value) {
            // Current is new sorted head.
            current.next = sortedList;
            sortedList = current;
        } else {
            // Search list for correct position of current.
            Node search = sortedList;
            while(search.next != null && current.value > search.next.value)
                search = search.next;

            // current goes after search.
            current.next = search.next;
            search.next = current;
        }
    }

    return sortedList;
}
```

See it run in JavaScript: http://jsfiddle.net/2LDGD/2/

Answer (score -2):

well sry, i dont have much time to read your code but one of the best ways i used in such problems is to create a "swap function", that uses in every sort algorithm, then you can implement every algorithm you want and change the swap function with yours and of course custom traverse commands